# Appending dictionary items in to Array<Dictionary<String, String>>

Tags: swift

Let me create these 3 dictionaries:

```
var animal1 = ["name":"lion", "footCount":"4", "move":"run"]
var animal2 = ["name":"Fish", "footCount":"0", "move":"swim"]
var animal3 = ["name":"bird", "footCount":"2", "move":"fly"]
```

And then let me create this array:

```
var myArray= [[String : String]()]
```

and then let me append above dictionaries in to myArray

```
myArray.append(animal1)
myArray.append(animal2)
myArray.append(animal3)
```

I see 4 items if I run below code

```
print(myArray.count)
```

because the array is created with one empty item: `var myArray= [[String : String]()]`
So I need to use below code all the time:

```
myArray.removeFirst()
```

**My question is:** 
Is there another alternative array defination to append above dictionaries? Because I must execute above code all the time if I use this array defination:

```
var myArray= [[String : String]()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty array of dictionaries like this:

```
var myArray= [[String : String]]()
```

Note that the `()`s are outside of the outer `[]`s. Your attempt of `[String : String]()]` is an array literal containing one element of an empty dictionary, whereas you should be calling the initialiser for the array type of `[[String : String]]` (aka `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>`).

Since you have all the elements you want in the array already, you could just do:

```
var myArray = [animal1, animal2, animal3]
```

as well.

---

Seeing how all your dictionary keys are the same though, you should really create a custom struct for this:

```
struct Animal {
    let name: String
    let footCount: Int
    let move: String
}
```

And your array can be:

```
var myArray= [Animal]()
```